# PHP login/register system with profile-pages

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, registration

I made some code for a PHP login and register system, the only problem is that when a user logs in his username is just posted (`$_POST`) on his profile page. So my question is: How do I create a login system that when the user logs in his username is Not displayed but the system see's the username in Mysql and display his real name? sorry for the vague explanation but i don't realy know how to explane.

My code: (for the login form)

```
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];

    $con=mysql_connect("host", "user", "pass");

    mysql_select_db("db"); 

    $username=$_POST['username']; 
    $password=$_POST['password']; 

    $user=mysql_real_escape_string($username); 
    $pass=mysql_real_escape_string($password); 

    $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM login where 
    username='$user' AND  
    password='$pass' ");  

    $count=mysql_num_rows($query); 
    if($count==1)  
        /* $count checks if username and password are in same row */
    { 


 $hour = time() + 3600;   
    /* $hour sets cookie storage time for 1 hour */

    /* setcookie() function sets cookie after login */
 setcookie("username", $username, $hour);  
 setcookie("password", $password, $hour); 

 header("");  
    /* header() function redirect user to members page */
} 
else
{  
print " <link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"css/global_profile.css\" />\n";
print "<h3>" . "Username or password is incorrect" . "</h3>"; 
}
```

Comment: Do you have a database, with all the user info ready?

Comment: Yes, ik have a database with the users info: Birthday, First name, Last name, E-mail, username, password.

Comment: Can you please post the code you are working on , and kindly read "How to post a Question" so that it gets easier for everyone to answer your question .

Comment: Are you seriously storing passwords in plain text?

Comment: Worse, you're storing passwords in a cookie in plain text. Big no-no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out,

[Simple Register-Login-Logoff System](http://forum.codecall.net/topic/36372-simple-register-login-logoff-system/)

[Register and Login (User Account System)](http://betterphp.co.uk/playlist.html?pid=A8C368A12314F07E)

[Registering Users and allowing them to edit their details](http://www.ssbits.com/tutorials/2010/site-members-registering-users-and-allowing-them-to-edit-their-details/)

[Making A Cool Login System With PHP, MySQL & jQuery](http://tutorialzine.com/2009/10/cool-login-system-php-jquery/)

[How to Create a Secure Login Script in PHP and MySQL](http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL)

[Register-login](http://www.zymic.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=4034)

[PHP Login Page Example](http://www.9lessons.info/2009/09/php-login-page-example.html)

Hope help you.

Answer (score 2):

Here ive put together a simple login script for you (because im lil bored ;p), have a scan through it and perhaps it will be of some interest, it uses PDO for the database connection as the mysql_ functions are soon tobe deprecated.

```
<?php
session_start();

/**
 * Table
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `login` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pass_hash` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pass_salt` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `birthday` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `firstname` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=0 ;

 */

//DB Stuff
define('DBHOST','127.0.0.1');
define('DBNAME','yourdb');
define('DBUSER','root');
define('DBPASS','toor');
//End Config:---


//Open a PDO Database connection
try {
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=".DBHOST.";dbname=".DBNAME, DBUSER, DBPASS);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
}catch (Exception $e){
    die('Cannot connect to mySQL server.');
}


class Login{
    public $db;
    public $user;
    public $pass;
    public $error;
    // sha512
    public $algo = '$6';
    // Cost parameter, 25k iterations
    public $cost = '$rounds=25000$';

    function __construct(PDO $db){
        $this->db = $db;
        $this->global_salt = sha1($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
    }

    function make_seed(){
        list($usec, $sec) = explode(' ', microtime());
        return (float) $sec + ((float) $usec * 100000);
    }

    function unique_salt(){
        $salt = null;
        mt_srand($this->make_seed());
        for($i=0;$i < mt_rand(1,10);$i++){
            $salt = sha1($this->global_salt.$salt.mt_rand().uniqid().microtime(true));
        }
        return substr($salt,0,16);
    }

    function hash($password){
        $this->salt = $this->unique_salt();
        $this->full_hash = crypt($password, $this->algo.$this->cost.$this->salt);
        $this->full_salt = substr($this->full_hash, 0, 33);
        $this->hashed_password = substr($this->full_hash, 33);
        return $this->full_hash;
    }

    /**
     * Validate the given crypto hash against the given password
     */
    function check_password($hash, $salt, $password){
        $hash = ($this->algo.$this->cost.$salt.'$'.$hash);
        if($hash == crypt($password, substr($hash, 0, 33))){
            //Regenerate new hash and salt for given password
            $this->update_keys();
            $this->status = true;
            $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
            $_SESSION['username'] = $this->user;
            return true;
        }else{
            $this->status = false;
            return false;
        }
    }

    function process_login(){
        if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

            $this->user   = (isset($_SESSION['userParam']) && isset($_POST[$_SESSION['userParam']]))?$_POST[$_SESSION['userParam']]:null;
            $this->pass   = (isset($_SESSION['passParam']) && isset($_POST[$_SESSION['passParam']]))?$_POST[$_SESSION['passParam']]:null;
            $this->create = (isset($_SESSION['createParam']) && isset($_POST[$_SESSION['createParam']]))?$_POST[$_SESSION['createParam']]:null;

            $cont = true;
            if($this->user == null || strlen($this->user) <= 2){$this->set_error('user','Please enter a username!'); $cont=false;}
            if($this->pass == null || strlen($this->pass) <= 2){$this->set_error('pass','Please enter a password!'); $cont=false;}

            if($cont==true){
                //Alls good continue
                if($this->create != null && $this->create=='1'){
                    //Check user for new account
                    if($this->check_user()==true){$this->set_error('user','Username already taken.');return;}
                    //Create account
                    $this->create_account();
                }else{
                    $this->check_login();
                }
            }else{
                //Error with form
                $this->set_error('global','Please fill in login form!');
            }
        }
    }

    function check_user(){
        $sql = 'SELECT 1 FROM login WHERE username=:username';
        $statement = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $statement->bindParam(':username', $this->user, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement->execute();
        $result = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if(!empty($result)){return true;}else{return false;}
    }

    function check_login(){
        $sql = 'SELECT pass_hash, pass_salt FROM login WHERE username=:username';
        $statement = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $statement->bindParam(':username', $this->user, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement->execute();
        $result = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        $this->check_password($result['pass_hash'], $result['pass_salt'], $this->pass);
    }

    function create_account(){
        //Create new account
        $this->hash($this->pass);
        $sql = 'INSERT into login (username, pass_hash, pass_salt) VALUES (:username, :pass_hash, :pass_salt)';
        $statement = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $statement->bindParam(':username', $this->user, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement->bindParam(':pass_hash', $this->hashed_password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement->bindParam(':pass_salt', $this->salt, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement->execute();

        $this->status = true;
        $_SESSION['logged_in']=true;
    }

    function update_keys(){
        //Update account password hash & salt
        $this->hash($this->pass);
        $sql = 'UPDATE login SET pass_hash=:pass_hash, pass_salt=:pass_salt WHERE username=:username';
        $statement = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $statement->bindParam(':username', $this->user, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement->bindParam(':pass_hash', $this->hashed_password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement->bindParam(':pass_salt', $this->salt, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement->execute();

        $this->status = true;
        $_SESSION['logged_in']=true;
    }

    function get_user_info(){
        $sql = "SELECT birthday,firstname,lastname,email FROM `login` WHERE username = :username";
        $sql = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $sql->bindParam(':username', $_SESSION['username'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $sql->execute();
        return $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

    static function logout(){
        unset($_SESSION['logged_in']);
        session_regenerate_id(true);
        exit(header('Location: ./index.php'));
    }

    function set_error($type,$value){
        $this->error[$type]=$value;
    }

    function error($type){
        echo (isset($this->error[$type]))?$this->error[$type]:null;
    }

}//END Login class

//Logout handler
if(isset($_GET['logout'])){ Login::logout(); }

$login = new Login($db);

//Login handler
$login->process_login();

//Check login status
if(isset($_SESSION['logged_in']) && $_SESSION['logged_in']==true){
    //Logged in
    $userinfo = $login->get_user_info();
    echo '<h1>Welcome,'.$userinfo['firstname'].'</h1>';
    echo '<pre>'.print_r($userinfo,true).'</pre>';
    echo '<p><a href="?logout">Logout</a></p>';

}else{
    //Not Logged In
    //Show login form & create uniqie parrams for user/pass/create post keys
    $_SESSION['userParam']   = sha1(uniqid().microtime(true));
    $_SESSION['passParam']   = sha1(uniqid().microtime(true));
    $_SESSION['createParam'] = sha1(uniqid().microtime(true));
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Simple Login</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Please login:</h1>

<?php $login->error('global'); ?>

    <form method="POST" action="">
      <label for="user">Username :&nbsp; </label>
      <input type="text" name="<?=$_SESSION['userParam'];?>" size="29" required/> <?php $login->error('user'); ?>
      <br />
      <label for="pass">Password :&nbsp; </label>
      <input type="text" name="<?=$_SESSION['passParam'];?>" size="29"  required/> <?php $login->error('pass'); ?>
      <br />
      <input type="submit" value="Login">&nbsp; and create my account (demo):<input type="checkbox" name="<?=$_SESSION['createParam'];?>" value="1">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Don't encrypt passwords! They should be hashed using a password hash, such as bcrypt / scrypt.

Comment: Bcrypt uses `$2y$`; besides that, what's up with all the weird salt calculations? Salt generation should not be influenced by outside data, such as `HTTP_HOST`.

Comment: Just being abit crazy my bad, tho HTTP_HOST is just part of the salt, `$this->global_salt.$salt.mt_rand().uniqid().microtime(true)` and it has its own cost of between 1-10 iterations, beside the pass_hash and salt are regenerated upon each login.